# Quickly getting all symbols for feature layer with ArcObjects?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, symbology

I have a `FeatureLayer` and I want to enumerate all the symbols used in it. Simple way - it is to call `SymbolByFeature` for each features. Something approximately likes:

```
Dim l as IFeatureLayer
Dim c as IFeatureCursor
Dim r as IFeatureRender
Dim f as IFeature
Dim s as ISymbol

Set r = IGeoFeatureLayer(l).Renderer
Set c = l.Search(0, True)
Set f = c.NextFeature

Do Until f is Nothing
  Set s = r.SymbolByFeature(f)
  [...]  ' check whether this symbol is in collection and add it if necessary
  Set f = c.NextFeature
Loop
```

The problem with this method is that it too long, especially when there is a lot of features in the feature layer.

Is there a faster way to get a collection of all the symbols in a feature layer?

Comment: What kind of IFeatureRenderer are you using?

Comment: @Kirk - It can be arbitrary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is my solution (in C++)

```
esriCarto::IFeatureLayerPtr l = get_layer(); // it is taken from somewhere
esriCarto::ILegendInfoPtr info = l;

for (long i = 0; i < info->LegendGroupCount; ++i) {
    esriCarto::ILegendGroupPtr group = info->GetLegendGroup(i);

    for (long j = 0; j != group->ClassCount; ++j) {
            esriCarto::ILegendClassPtr c = group->GetClass(j);
            some_function_to_add_symbol(c->Symbol);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 yes, this looks much simpler.  Keep in mind for a uniqevaluerenderer there might be a symbol for "all other values" even though there might not be any features that actually have that symbol.

Answer (score 4):

You could put in if statements to handle each different coclass that implements [IFeatureRenderer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IFeatureRenderer_Interface/0012000004wn000000/).  e.g. For [IUniqueValueRenderer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//001200000rrq000000), you can loop through each value, and get the symbol associated with the value.  For [ISimpleRenderer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ISimpleRenderer_Interface/001200000qs2000000/), just get the single symbol, etc.

Comment: Thank you. This approach works, but it is too wordy. I would like some more generic way.